# How to access property of a nested object?

Tags: javascript, function, object, properties, underscore.js

I have the following Javascript object:

```
doc = {};
doc.title = 'a title';
doc.date = 'a date';
doc.send = {
    date: new Date(),
    sender: 'a sender',
    receiver: 'a receiver'
};
```

And i have the following function:

```
doSomething(item, property) {
    console.log(item[property];
}
```

It works if i call `doSomething(doc, 'date')`, but it doesn't work if i use `doSomething(doc, 'send.date')`.
Since that function have to be reusable, how to let it handling any type of property, including nested one?

I see that `lodash` could be helpful with `_.get`, but i'm using `underscore` that not include that method. In addition i prefer not to use and install other libraries. Any idea?

Comment: Dup? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2631001/javascript-test-for-existence-of-nested-object-key

Comment: @elclanrs The question you linked is about checking for existence, and this one is about accessing.

Comment: Pretty much the same thing, if you can access it then it exists...

Answer (score 0):

You can write a function to find (nested) property value, for example:

```
function findDeepProp(obj, prop) {
    return prop.split('.').reduce((r, p)=> r[p], obj)
}
findDeepProp(doc, 'title'); // a title
findDeepProp(doc, 'send.sender'); // a sender
```

Comment: This will throw an error on nested properties that don't exist.

Comment: And it only works on one level of nesting. May or may not be important.

Comment: @elclanrs sure, why not to throw when trying to access properties of `undefined`? This is just how javascript works

Comment: I would avoid exceptions. All you need is `.reduce((r, p) => r && r[p], obj)`

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit dangerous depending on what you're trying to do, I recommend you to read [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval), but I think this will work:

```
doSomething = function(element, property){
    console.log(eval("element." + property));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you wanted to check more than one level of nesting you could use a function that uses recursion.

```
var doc = {
  title: 'a title', date: 'a date',
  send: { date: +new Date(), sender: 'a sender', receiver: 'a receiver',
    thing: {
      fullname: { first: 'Bob', last: 'Smith' }
    }
  }
}

function findDeepProp(obj, prop) {

  // create an array from the props argument
  var target = prop.split('.'), out;

  // iteration function accepts an object and target array
  (function iterate(obj, target) {

    // remove the first array element and assign it to tmp
    var tmp = target.shift();

    // if target has no more elements and tmp
    // exists as a key in the object passed into iterate()
    // return its value
    if (target.length === 0 && obj[tmp]) return out = obj[tmp];

    // if the key exists in the object passed into iterate()
    // but it is an object, run iterate() with that object
    // and the reduced target array
    if (obj[tmp] && typeof obj[tmp] === 'object') iterate(obj[tmp], target);

    return;
  }(obj, target));

  return out;
}

findDeepProp(doc, 'send.thing.fullname.first') // Bob
findDeepProp(doc, 'send.thing.fullname.last') // Smith
```

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/qjd1k03p/)